# How to resolve Visual Studio TFS Mapping Error (The working (phantom) folder is already in use by workspace...)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am at wits end on this one and I believe I've searched every resource available including SO but nothing is working.

I presumably had some folder which was previously mapped at some point in time to a location which no longer exists; but Visual Studio and/or TFS is holding this phantom reference somewhere that I cannot find. So the error dialog looks like this:

[image]

So in short, the issue isn't that I cannot remove (delete) the workspace but rather that when I attempt to add the workspace when there clearly isn't one and subsequently map to this particular folder; I am presented with a dialog nagging about a workspace that I can't validate to even exist.

The things I've already tried are:

Delete the workspace from the TFS Server (using the tf utility)

- tf workspace /delete [WORKSPACE]
  Delete the workspace from my local workstation
- tf workspace /delete /server [SERVER/Collection] /[WORKSPACE]
- Other variations of the delete workspace command as well

Removed the workspace from within the VS2015 UI

- File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces
- Workspace (drop down) -> Workspaces -> Remove

Delete cached TFS data

- "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\"

Removed and re-installed Visual Studio 2015 from ground up

There have also been a plethora of other suggestions I've tried but those were the most popular mentioned; and I still get this annoying dialog.

If I knew where the information was being stored I believe I'd be at the door of resolution but I cannot find any resources that I haven't already covered to determine where its getting this information.

I could venture into the registry but I dare not without having at least a clue as to where I need to look.

So are there any other locations where this information could potentially be getting pulled?

Comment: @Does this issue only occur on your client? Please check if this issue occurs on other VS client machines. And try to use the "tf workspaces" command to check whether the workspace existing on the current or remote computer. Also try to reboot the TFS server and your VS client machine, then try it again. If the problem still exist, please share the detail steps to reproduce this issue, and check the event viewer or any other related logs and share them here for further troubleshooting.

Comment: The issue seems to be only specific to my workstation. Using the tf workspaces command showed that the workspace existed on my local client as well as the remote TFS server. I deleted both of them successfully but when I add the workspace back (whether having the same or different name) and try to map to the specific folder the issue is again prevalent. At this point I've aborted any effort to resolve the issue and have opted to simply using another folder. I've suspected that the issue is likely unique and not worth wasting anyones time. Thank for the response

Answer (score 0):

So, the workaround is deleting the workspace and create a new one ,then remap the workspace to another folder.

Comment: I'll accept this as a recommended and useful workaround. However, it is not a resolution to the issue which is what the initial question was targeting as an answer. To the contrary, it was something that was of fore-knowledge prior to the question.Thanks.